# Frozen interface even with new thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, user-interface

Hi i'd like to do a task out of the EDT because i don't want to froze my interface each time i click on a button :

The long-time task is the function paintComponent of fBPC then i have to create new thread for fBPC.repaint(). But even with this new thread my interface still freeze ( because i'd like to click on my button while the task is done in background ), how can i do? Maybe should i create the thread in an other part ?

```
new Thread(new Runnable(){

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    fBPC.repaint();
                    System.out.println("toto");
                    if (SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()){
                        System.out.println("titi");
                    }
                }
            }).start();
```

Comment: `paintComponent` must **never** be the time consuming task!

Comment: calling repaint() on a separate thread won't change anything. What repaint() does is to ask the panel to repaint itself, in the event dispatch thread. If paintComponent takes too much time, then it's probably that you're doing things inside the method that doesn't have much to do with painting. This is what must be moved to another thread.

Comment: @JBNizet Yeah but i have no other choices because the thing i'm painting is an image composed of points which are calculated in a huge for boucle and i have to recalculate all these points every time i click on my buttons on the interface that's why i need to execute my function which calculate the image in the paintComponent method.

Comment: Compute the points, in a separate thread, and when they're ready to be painted, then only call repaint().